# Problemas con eventos de selección en un GridControl de DevExpress

Tags: visual-studio, eventos, devexpress, vba

Tengo un **gridControl** de **DevExpress**, en el que necesito obtener las filas seleccionadas constantemente. He utilizado el evento **SelectionChanged** pero este evento es llamado varias veces durante la selección, y provoca que el funcionamiento no sea realmente el que quiero. Necesitaría que solo entrara una vez y me diera el valor de la fila seleccionada, porque depende de la fila que seleccione tengo que realizar una operación distinta.
El lenguaje utilizado es Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Si desea obtener datos de las filas seleccionadas, puede llamar al  método [GridView.GetSelectedRows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetSelectedRows.method) para obtener una colección de identificadores de fila seleccionados. Luego, ejecute esta colección y obtenga un valor de celda usando el  método [GridView.GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic).

Aquí hay un fragmento de código de muestra:

**[VB.NET]**

```
Dim selectedRows() As Integer = <tu GridView>.GetSelectedRows()  
For Each rowHandle As Integer In selectedRows  
     If rowHandle >= 0 Then  
         Dim cellValue = <tu GridView>.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, <tu columna>)  
     End If  
Next rowHandle
```

**[C#]**

```
int[] selectedRows = <tu GridView>.GetSelectedRows();  
foreach (int rowHandle in selectedRows)  
{  
     if(rowHandle >= 0)  
         var cellValue = <tu GridView>.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, <tu columna>);  
}
```